# Account logon errors in security log after password change

Tags: 2010, service, password

We recently changed the password of Farm admin account on our WFE servers.
After that , there are multiple audit failure occurrence relating to this account daily.
[image: error]

The audit failure means that an account is unable to authenticate against a service.
I have noticed that is the failure audit is initiated by the system process w3wp.exe

So I did a check on IIS application pools for any application pool which is not started.
All of the application pools are started. So my question what events could have initiated these events?
IS there anything else I can check that will help find the cause of this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can say this, This is normal behavior. I witness this in my environment almost every year when we change password for our Managed accounts( Farm admin, App Pool, other services accounts).

Please clear the config Cache on all servers and then observe it.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx

I am sure you already reset IIS on all servers in farm

Comment: Thanks Waqas. I'll try clearing the configuration cache. Did it resolve the issue on your farm?

Comment: Yes, it resolved the issue